Can't redeem my denied-boarding vouchers
I was involuntary denied boarding on a Lufthansa flight and got these compensation vouchers to redeem. The problem is that I don't know where to redeem those. I have tried to do it online, but it doesn't work. I have even tried at the airport but maybe I went to the wrong desk. Does anyone here know what I could do?

What do the vouchers say on them?  Who gave them to you?  How much are they worth?

What do you mean with "redeem"? To be used to reduce a price of a flight? Or to get cash? At airport you should go to the ticket sales desk (not the check-in). In any case, you should have a code, and you put such code when buying ticket on Lufthansa website (it doesn't work on other sites)

What happened at the airport? Whom did you speak with and what did the agent say?

Firstly, just know that if you signed something, you were defrauded of your legal rights. You should've got EUR 250, EUR 400 or EUR 600 in CASH (bank transfer) depending on the route.
Contact Lufthansa and tell them 1) you can't redeem it despite multiple attemps and 2) they didn't tell you you were actually entitled to CASH compensation, and that you therefore request them to cancel the voucher and immediately pay compensation in cash (and also any expenses you incurred while waiting for the new flight unless you abandoned the trip), and that you'll take legal action if they refuse.

Pro tip for everyone: if someone screws you over and they offer you "compensation", they are usually trying to avoid giving you the actual compensation you deserve.
Always say no until you have checked your rights.

If I remember correctly (I've only had this issue once with Lufthansa), they offer the choice, or at least used to offer the choice between cash compensation or vouchers worth twice the legally required cash compensation. If you fly often enough with Lufthansa and know that you can make use of the vouchers within the next three years (I believe that is the validity), it is usually a much better deal for the passenger to take the vouchers instead of clinging onto the legal right to claim cash compensation.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo OP's likely an inexperienced traveller (being 19 years old), so likely seen as easy prey to save money on. I bet the voucher the handling agent offered is a pittance compared to what he's entitled to :/

Hardly: I've had Aviator at Arlanda try to f*k me over the same way in 2023 for an overbooked Austrian flight ARN-VIE. They offered me a €50 voucher as a "goodwill gesture for the inconvenience" which said in the small print I'd waive my right to further compensation by signing it. I effectively told them to shove it up their backsides. They were so bitter as to then lie on the system by writing I was voluntarily offloaded. The court hearing with Austrian was 100% "he said, she said", and luckily the judge decided "on the balance of probabilities" to believe me and so awarded me €250+expenses

Always be wary of “compensation” by airlines. Qatar airways for example can give you vouchers “plus 20%”, or cash. It turns out the 20% is not over the total, but before taxes. Long story short the voucher is worth the same or less than the total. Just get cash where possible.
